# How to fully scroll inside relative layout in android in jellybean(4.1.2)screen?

Tags: android

How to fully scroll inside relative layout in android jellybean (4.1.2) screen?
When we run on this (4.1.2) screen, the layout (button imgv5) is hidden in the   bottom. Also, scrollview is working but not fully. Can u please help me?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

         <ScrollView 
                android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"         
                 >
                <!-- android:scrollbars="vertical" -->
         <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                 >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:hint="Enter Name"
                    style="@style/editText"
                    android:clickable="false" 
                    android:cursorVisible="false" 
                    android:focusable="false" 
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtMobile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/edtName"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:hint="Enter Mobile-Number"
                    style="@style/editText"
                    android:clickable="false" 
                    android:cursorVisible="false" 
                    android:focusable="false" 
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                     />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtAddres"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/edtMobile"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:hint="Enter Address"
                    style="@style/editText"
                    android:clickable="false" 
                    android:cursorVisible="false" 
                    android:focusable="false" 
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                     />

                 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtVehicleModel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/edtAddres"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:hint="Enter Vehicle-model"
                    style="@style/editText"
                    android:clickable="false" 
                    android:cursorVisible="false" 
                    android:focusable="false" 
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                     />

                 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtVehicleNo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/edtVehicleModel"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:hint="Enter Vehicle-number"
                    style="@style/editText"
                    android:clickable="false" 
                    android:cursorVisible="false" 
                    android:focusable="false" 
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                     />

                 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtServiceType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/edtVehicleNo"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:hint="Enter Service-type"
                    style="@style/editText"
                    android:clickable="false" 
                    android:cursorVisible="false" 
                    android:focusable="false" 
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                     />


                 <ImageView                 
                             android:id="@+id/imgV1"
                             android:layout_width="125dp"
                             android:layout_height="55dp" 
                             android:clickable="true"
                             android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                             android:layout_below="@+id/edtServiceType"
                             android:background="#2196F3"
                             android:scaleType="fitXY"
                             />

                          <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/ImageViewText1"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgV1"
                             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgV1"
                             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgV1"
                             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgV1"
                             android:layout_margin="1dp"
                             android:gravity="center"
                             android:text="Front View"
                             android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                 <ImageView
                             android:id="@+id/imgV2"
                             android:layout_width="125dp"
                             android:layout_height="55dp" 
                             android:clickable="true"
                             android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                             android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgV1"
                             android:background="#2196F3" 
                             android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

                  <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/ImageViewText2"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgV2"
                             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgV2"
                             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgV2"
                             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgV2"
                             android:layout_margin="1dp"
                             android:gravity="center"
                             android:text="Rear View"
                             android:textColor="#ffffff" />


                  <ImageView
                             android:id="@+id/imgV3"
                             android:layout_width="125dp"
                             android:layout_height="55dp" 
                             android:clickable="true"
                             android:layout_below="@+id/imgV1"
                             android:layout_marginTop="15dp"  
                             android:background="#2196F3"
                             android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                   <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/ImageViewText3"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgV3"
                             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgV3"
                             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgV3"
                             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgV3"
                             android:layout_margin="1dp"
                             android:gravity="center"
                             android:text="Right View"
                             android:textColor="#ffffff" />


                  <ImageView
                             android:id="@+id/imgV4"
                             android:layout_width="125dp"
                             android:layout_height="55dp" 
                             android:clickable="true"
                             android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgV3"
                             android:background="#2196F3" 
                             android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

                   <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/ImageViewText4"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgV4"
                             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgV4"
                             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgV4"
                             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgV4"
                             android:layout_margin="1dp"
                             android:gravity="center"
                             android:text="Left View"
                             android:textColor="#ffffff" />


                    <ImageView
                             android:id="@+id/imgV5"
                             android:layout_width="125dp"
                             android:layout_height="55dp"
                             android:clickable="true"
                             android:layout_below="@+id/imgV3"                       
                             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                             android:background="#2196F3" 
                             android:gravity="center"
                             android:scaleType="fitXY"
                             />

                           <!--   android:layout_marginLeft="125dp" -->

                     <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/ImageViewText5"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgV5"
                             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgV5"
                             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgV5"
                             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgV5"
                             android:layout_margin="1dp"
                             android:gravity="center"
                             android:text="Job Sheet"
                             android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                    <!--  <Button
                         android:id="@+id/btnCreateId"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                         android:text="Create ID" 
                         style="@style/button"/> -->

         </RelativeLayout>
         </ScrollView>

          <Button
                         android:id="@+id/btnCreateId"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                         android:text="Create ID" 
                         style="@style/enter code here button"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your scroll view above of ImageViewText5   using  **android:layout_above**

```
            <ScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ImageViewText5"
            android:fillViewport="true"         
             >
```